what is the problem with this public api ? i can get response back
im trying to crawl FlyToday.ir for foreign hotels price rates .
the problem is
there is an api in the network tab called by post method and has response in return
but when i want to call it (with all request headers ) in postman
it does not fetch any data and respond with 400 bad request
this is the api address : https://api.flytoday.ir/api/V1/hotel/Availability
this is the url : https://www.flytoday.ir/hotel/search/hotelavailability?hotelId=367271&cityId=924&checkIn=2024-08-05&checkOut=2024-08-06&adt[0]=1&chd[0]=0&chdAges[0]=&dateLang=fa&countryCode=TR#dialog
headers are :
:authority:api.flytoday.ir
:method:
POST
:scheme:
https
Accept:/
Accept-Language:
fa-IR
Authorization:
Bearer null
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Content-Length:270
Content-Type:
application/json
Origin:https://www.flytoday.ir
Pragma:
no-cache
Priority:
u=1, i
Referer:https://www.flytoday.ir/
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
X-App:www.flytoday.ir
X-Path:https://www.flytoday.ir/hotel/search/hotelavailability?hotelId=367271&cityId=924&checkIn=2024-08-05&checkOut=2024-08-06&adt[0]=1&chd[0]=0&chdAges[0]=&dateLang=fa&countryCode=TR
X-Token:
4f63416d49375362534e5247534763704d62475267372b744a36565a7044507250746178687847617a486d4a6b537157664e4f54616e3657772b762f356c4c56
could anyone help?
thanks in advance
i have tried in postman but bad request 400 all the time

Did you ask their developer support for help?

not yet Nico ..
